# Need multiple databases with different names but same base configurations

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, copy

I am Using myphpadmin to manage a mysql (mariadb) on a linux server.   A database with base configurations is ready and needs to be replicated to 7 distinct databases for use with 7 different countries on the same server.  The data base name will be different in all cases.

How can this be done with myadminphp?

Comment: You can try enabling binary logging:


  [1]: https://www.sqlshack.com/learn-mysql-an-overview-of-mysql-binary-logs/#:~:text=Enabling%20the%20binary%20logs,MySQL%5CMySQL%20Server%208.0%20directory.

Comment: By `A database with base configurations is ready and needs to be replicated to 7 distinct databases for use with 7 different countries on the same server` did you mean you want to create 7 more mysql instances on the same server , OR you would create 7 more schemas within the same mysql instance ?